# Ember.Component's sendAction() to view target

Tags: ember.js

`sendAction()` in an Ember.Component bubbles to controller by default which is expected. But i have 2,3 actions which i rather need to send to corresponding view which is using the component. In templates we set action to view using `target=view`. Can we do that?.

**Update**: Currently as a work around I am sending my view object to component which from there calls `view.send()` to send the action. But i feel this is not correct.

Comment: I believe if you just use an {{action "someAction"}} within the template of the component and handle it within the actions hash of the component that targets the component itself.

Comment: sorry if my english was poor..but What I am asking is when once we get in to that actions hash of component, if i need to bubble up action we need to use `sendAction()` method. But then that only bubbles up to controller. I am not able to bubble up to view which was using the component.

Comment: I think I know what you mean now will submit an answer to elaborate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok after some thinking I believe i know that you mean. If you have a component and you have a action it will be handled by the component itself. If you want to send a action outside the component you would use sendAction.

Now to target the view of which holds your component since your component is base on a view, you can probably do `this.get('parentView')` to get the parent view and then chain `send('nameOfAction')`

So it would be `this.get('parentView').send('nameOfAction')` from within the component action and it will then trigger the action on the parent view of which the component is embedded.

So in your component you could have:

```
 App.DemoCompComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
   actions: {
     internalTrigger: function() {
       //just an alert to make sure it fired
       alert('Internal action was caught on component');
       //this should target parent view component is in
       this.get('parentView').send('viewTriggerTest');
    }
  } 
 });
```

Now lets say you have you component in the index template you could:

The template would be:

```
   <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
     <h2>Inside Index Template</h2>
       {{demo-comp}}
   </script>
```

The Index View Code would be:

```
 App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
   actions: {
     viewTriggerTest: function() {
       alert('View Trigger Test Worked on Index!');
     }
   }
 });
```

Here is a jsbin
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/reyexuko/1/edit

Comment: Thanks..i was not expecting this.get('parentView') to work in component :)

Comment: If you look just below the title of [the Class on in the Ember API docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html) it is specified which class has been extended to create the class in question. As you can see, `Em.Component` extends `Em.View` and the `parentView` property is available.

Comment: ^ i understand what are you saying..But AFAIK components actually meant to be fully independent.If you are allowed to access View class object of parent, it didn't met that requirement...i was rather expecting some kinda bubbling option but i will take `parentView` option for now :)

Answer (score 0):

For latest Ember 2.9 the recommended approach is to pass a `closure action` to the child component. The property `target` and `parentView` are private ones.